# Read Python XML with tag and text in one element

Tags: python, xml

I have the XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <title>
    <tag>A</tag>
    X
  </title>
</document>
```

and I'd like to read it with Python such that I could reconstruct the file exactly. For example, I need to retain `A` as a `<tag>`, and `X` as text.

The default XML implementation seems to have problems with the combination of `<tag>` and `text` in the `<title>` element. `itertext()` doesn't retain `A` as a `<tag>`, and the regular iteration doesn't capture `X` at all:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("a.xml")
r = tree.getroot()

title = r[0]

print(list(title.itertext()))
print([c for c in title])
print(repr(title.text))
```

```py
['\n    ', 'A', '\n    X\n  ']
[<Element 'tag' at 0x7fc11c130c20>]
'\n    '
```

Any hints?

Comment: title element is root element in that case, is that the case?

Comment: Thanks for the response! No, there's a wrapping element, I thought it doesn't make a difference. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Can you include what is the expected behavior from your example?

Comment: @BoppreH Edited accordingly. (I need to be able to differentiate between `<tag>`s and text.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ElementTree stores A as `text` attribute of the "tag"-element and X as `tail` attribute of the same element.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = ET.fromstring('<title><tag>A</tag>X</title>')
tag = xml.find("tag")
print(tag.text) # prints A
print(tag.tail) # prints X
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating root element shows how Elements and text are distributed. `'\n    X\n  '` text is `tail` attribute of  `tag` Element

```
>>> for e in r.getiterator():
...   print((e, e.text, e.tail))
... 
(<Element 'document' at 0x7f2f21844278>, '\n  ', None)
(<Element 'title' at 0x7f2f212e3188>, '\n    ', '\n')
(<Element 'tag' at 0x7f2f212e31d8>, 'A', '\n    X\n  ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to convert a single XML element back into text, there's [ElementTree.tostring](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring). Using your example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("a.xml")
r = tree.getroot()

title = r[0]

print(ET.tostring(title, encoding='unicode'))
#<title>
#    <tag>A</tag>
#    X
#  </title>
```

Note it even included the last space before `</title>`. The "unicode" part is required unless you want a bytes object back.

Comment: How to get `<tag>` and text separately?

Comment: Using treuss's answer ;) From your question it wasn't clear if you needed the output as a single string, or as something to be processed one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

The `<title>` tag doesn’t have any printable text, it have only a line break. I think what you search is the tail of `<tag>` element:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_string = """
<title>
  <tag>A</tag>
  X
</title>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

for elem in root.iter():
    if elem.tag == "title":
        print(repr(elem.text))
    if elem.tag == "tag":
        print(elem.text)
        print(elem.tail)
```

Output:

```
'\n  '
A

  X
```